# Exchange event receivers of lists

Tags: 2010, list, event-receivers

Recently i faced an interview question for which i am unable to find a suitable answer.

I was given a scenarion to implement, which goes like this.

There are two event receivers Ea and Eb, these are associated with Lists La and Lb respectively.

Once the system is deployed i can not change alter the recever.

One thing what i can think of is to use Featuree activeted and Deactivated events.
Associate Ea to La and Eb to Lb in activated, Ea to Lb and Eb to La in deactivated.

But, this is not how we use activated or deactivated events.

Could someone suggest anything on this.

Also can someone guess a scenario where this functionality will be helpful or it was just a tricky question.

Comment: What is the question that they asked you ?